# Posting image to Twitter API

Tags: objective-c, oauth, twitter

I am trying to upload a image to the twitter api. I am using PlainOAuth. Here's what I have:

```
oauth_token = accessToken;
oauth_token_secret = accessTokenSecret;
OAuth *oAuth = [[OAuth alloc] initWithConsumerKey:***** andConsumerSecret:****];
oAuth.oauth_token = accessToken;
oAuth.oauth_token_secret = accessTokenSecret;
oAuth.oauth_token_authorized = YES;
[oAuth release];

NSString *url = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json";
NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", @"status", [tweetStatus encodedURLParameterString]],
                   imageData, @"media[]",
                   nil];
NSDictionary *paramsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            imageData, @"media[]",
                            tweetStatus, @"status",
                            [accessToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], @"oauth_token",
                            nil];

NSString *oauth_header = [super oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"POST" andUrl:url andParams:paramsDict andTokenSecret:accessTokenSecret];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0f];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:[[params componentsJoinedByString:@"&"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"media[]\"; filename=\"media.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

[request addValue:oauth_header forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *responseString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

`responseString` is outputting blank. So I'm guessing there is a 404 error? if I remove the `media[]` info from either of my paramaters array, I get a oAuth error.

Please help!

Comment: u can use twitter framework instead of API

Comment: @NAZIK Yes, but for everything else I've used the API... So I don't want to import all their files into my project just for this one small feature.

Comment: which is your app's deployment target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *twitterViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

NSString *twitterText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", kBookingShareTwitterText, kBookingShareFlightURL, bookingId];
[twitterViewController setInitialText:twitterText];
[twitterViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
[self presentModalViewController:twitterViewController animated:YES];

[twitterViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {

    switch (result) {

        case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            break;

        case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            [self updateBookingWithFriendsInvitationFlag];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}];
```

Comment: That's not what I was going for. I'm working with multiple social networks, and this wouldn't be streamlined. I would like for it to post the picture in the background, without having any Twitter ViewControllers coming up.

Comment: And plus, TWTweetComposeViewController is deprecated in iOS 6.